# looping through a parsed array

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to loop through parsed array the array name is urls in which each element contains id, label, and size here is a picture showing the array

[image: the array I'm trying to parse]

I was able to loop through the array, but what I'm trying to do is to always access the first id in the urls array

```
    Alamofire.request("\(saveItLink)\(requestedLink)\(requestType)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)

            let jsonArray = json["urls"].array
            for ids in jsonArray!{
                let id = ids["id"].stringValue
                print(ids["id"].stringValue)

            }
            //print("JSON: \(json)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

        }
```

Here is what prints out in the consol

[image: parsed data]

How would I always access the first element of the urls array? and how would I save the value alone as a string value?

Comment: What do you mean by **How would I always access the first element of the urls array**, you want to access only first object of array ?

Comment: Yes the first link in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thanks to SwiftyJSON, you can easily get the value like that:

```
let firstId = json["urls"][0]["id"].stringValue
```

You haven't mentioned where do you want to save the value, but you can simply use the UserDefaults.
E.g:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(firstId, forKey: "your_key_for_accessing_the_value")
```

Also, I would suggest you to check if value is not empty:

```
let firstId = json["urls"][0]["id"].stringValue
if !firstId.isEmpty {
   UserDefaults.standard.set(firstId, forKey: "your_key_for_accessing_the_value")
} else {
   debugPrint("Id is empty")
}
```